# Are there any Wordpress websites that have scored over 90 on Google's PageSpeed Insights?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, google-pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

My website uses Wordpress.  I'd like to get over 90 on Google's PageSpeed Insights.

I guess the first thing I'd like to find out if that is even possible.

I was hoping to find a Wordpress site that scores 90 or above on Google's PageSpeed Insights.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible, and there are some ways to do this.
-You have to dequeue unnecessary js and CSS files loading on the landing page.
-Use premium page cache plugins, and follow their instructions.

Dequeue CSS, JS
-In your functions.php file use the hooks to dequeue files

```
 /*Site optimizations*/
/*Site optimizations*/
function remove_unnecessary_assets() {
    if (is_front_page()) { // only remove on the home page

        // remove CSS
        wp_dequeue_style('style-handler');

        // remove JS
        wp_dequeue_script('script-handler');
        
    }
};
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_unnecessary_assets', 999 );
```

After removing CSS, JSS make sure your site is working fine.

Then, use cache plugins:
[Wp Rocket](https://wp-rocket.me/) OR
[Nitropack](https://nitropack.io/)

Check Wp Rocket site on Google's PageSpeed

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to score 90+ for your Wordpress site is to deploy Nitropack.

Our wordpress site is now scoring 99 desktop, 92 mobile.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A clean WordPress install will score 99 in PageSpeed.